# Проблема в пагинации класса основанного на generic.list.ListView в Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

При процессе пагинации выводит вот такую ошибку:

> "TypeError at /goods/5/ object of type 'NoneType' has no len()"

**views.py**

```
class GoodsListView( PageNumberView, ListView, SortMixin, CategoryListMixin ):
    model = Good
    template_name = 'goods_index.html'
    paginate_by = 10
    cat = None

    def get( self, request, *args, **kwargs ):
        if self.kwargs[ 'pk' ] == None:
            self.cat = Category.objects.first()
        else:
            self.cat = Category.objects.get( pk = self.kwargs[ 'pk' ] )

        return super( GoodsListView, self ).get( request, *args, **kwargs )

    def get_context_data( self, **kwargs ):
        context = super( GoodsListView, self ).get_context_data( **kwargs )
        context[ 'category' ] = self.cat
        return context
```

**models.py**

```
class Good( models.Model ):

    name = models.CharField( max_length = 50, unique = True, 
        db_index = True, verbose_name = 'Название' )
    category = models.ForeignKey( Category, verbose_name = 'Категория' )
    description = models.TextField( verbose_name = 'Краткое описание' )
    content = models.TextField( verbose_name = 'Полное описание' )
    price = models.FloatField( db_index = True, verbose_name = 'Цена, руб.' )
    price_acc = models.FloatField( null = True, blank = True, 
        verbose_name = 'Цена с учетом скидки, руб.' )
    in_stock = models.BooleanField( default = True, db_index = True, 
        verbose_name = 'Есть в наличии' )
    featured = models.BooleanField( default = False, db_index = True, 
        verbose_name = 'Рекомендуемый'  )
    image = models.ImageField( upload_to = 'goods/list', 
        verbose_name = 'Основное изображение' )
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url( r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', GoodsListView.as_view(), name = 'goods_index' ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Знакомый код, из книги Дронова. Проблема не совсем там, где вы указали. Проблема в методе get_queryset, который будет идти за методом get_context_data. в него нужно добавить return goods, иначе метод ничего не возражает и возникает ошибка:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
    goods = Good.objects.filter(category=self.cat)
    if self.sort == "2":
        if self.order == "D":
            goods = goods.order_by("-in_stock", "name")
        else:
            goods = goods.order_by("in_stock", "name")
    elif self.sort == "1":
        if self.order == "D":
            goods = goods.order_by("-price", "name")
        else:
            goods = goods.order_by("price", "name")
    else:
        if self.order == "D":
            goods = goods.order_by("-name")
        else:
            goods = goods.order_by("name")
    return goods
```